# Methodic way to solve => Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MemberService

Tags: typescript, testing, dependency-injection, dependencies, nestjs

I am tasked with adding unit tests to a legacy project.

Before introducing unit tests on a given module, I am doing "smoke testing". Basically making the scaffolded "should be defined" pass.

Therefore I am facing the classical error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MemberService (NestWinston, ?, RedisService, RepoService, SqsService). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Object is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]
  })
```

How can I know for sure what is needed in that module?

It's a legacy project, so it's hard to get the information, and my collegues can't fully help me on that.

What would be a good method to solve this issue ?

EDIT: Here is the MemberService's constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
  private readonly sendMail: any;
  private algoliaClient: any;
  private index: AlgoliaSearch.SearchIndex;
  private readonly sendLog: any;

  constructor(
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER)
    private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
    private readonly redisService: RedisService,
    private readonly repoService: RepoService,
    private readonly sqsService: SqsService,
  ) {
    const { sendMessage: sendLog } = this.sqsService.initQueue('logs');
    this.sendLog = sendLog;
    const { sendMessage: sendMail } = this.sqsService.initQueue('mail');
    this.sendMail = sendMail;
    this.algoliaClient = AlgoliaSearch.default(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY);
    this.index = this.algoliaClient.initIndex(`${APP_ENV}_NETWORK_MEMBERS`);
  }
```

EDIT 2: Here is my testing module set up

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(DB_CONNECTION),
        RepoModule,
        RedisModule.register({
          url: REDIS_URL,
          autoResubscribe: false,
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        CacheService,
        MemberService,
        SqsService,
        {
          provide: WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER,
          useFactory: () =>
            Winston.createLogger({
              transports: [new Winston.transports.Console()],
            }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<MemberService>(MemberService);
  });
```

Comment: this is a common; look https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnestjs%5D%22Error%3A+Nest+can%27t+resolve+dependencies+of We could help you if you show us how is your `MemberService`'s `constructor` method, btw

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MicaelLevi, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: What I understand, the LoggerService is missing.

And provider are expected as per the MemberService constructor params.

Comment: yes. How is your testing module set up? you have to do something like what's shown here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing-1

Comment: Edited. For some reason, I can't import `LoggerService` inside my test module.

Comment: you could use its token which is the `LoggerService.name` ie., `'LoggerService'`

Answer (score 1):

From your shown code, the `@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER)` is in the wrong spot. You are overriding the `CacheService`'s injection token with `WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER` and not providing anything for `LoggerService` (which itself is an interface, getting transpiled to `{}`). Move the `@Inject()` line down by 1 to have it modify the `private readonly logger: LoggerService` instead and you should be good to go.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
  private readonly sendMail: any;
  private algoliaClient: any;
  private index: AlgoliaSearch.SearchIndex;
  private readonly sendLog: any;

  constructor(
    private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER)
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
    private readonly redisService: RedisService,
    private readonly repoService: RepoService,
    private readonly sqsService: SqsService,
  ) {
    const { sendMessage: sendLog } = this.sqsService.initQueue('logs');
    this.sendLog = sendLog;
    const { sendMessage: sendMail } = this.sqsService.initQueue('mail');
    this.sendMail = sendMail;
    this.algoliaClient = AlgoliaSearch.default(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY);
    this.index = this.algoliaClient.initIndex(`${APP_ENV}_NETWORK_MEMBERS`);
  }
```